# Adding/Updating key, val in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to set up an empty dictionary `ind_dict` at the beginning, and then when I get a pair of `(key, val)`. If the `key` already exists in the `ind_dict`, I will just add up the `val`(float type), otherwise I will add the new `(key, val)` pair.

Comment: You almost have answered your own question. Try transforming that into code. If your code doesn't give you the output you want, post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a use case for `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ind_dict = defaultdict(float)

for key, val in [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]:
    ind_dict[key] += val
```

Now:

```
>>> ind_dict
defaultdict(float, {'a': 4.0, 'b': 2.0})
```

> `defaultdict(default_factory[, ...]) --> dict with default factory`
>
> The default factory is called without arguments to produce
>   a new value when a key is not present, in **getitem** only.
>   A defaultdict compares equal to a dict with the same items.
>   All remaining arguments are treated the same as if they were
>   passed to the dict constructor, including keyword arguments.

Here the `default factory` is `float`. Calling `float()` gives you a `0.0`.
So you can directly add to it without any `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
def addFloatToFloatDic(tup,dic): 
    if tup[0] in dic:        # check if in dict, if so 
        dic[tup[0]] += tup[1]    # add value
    else:                    # else 
        dic[tup[0]] = tup[1]      # use as initial value

ind_dic = {}

addFloatToFloatDic(("k",12.1),ind_dic)
print (ind_dic)

addFloatToFloatDic(("k",12.1),ind_dic)
print (ind_dic)
```

Output:

```
{'k': 12.1}
{'k': 24.2}
```